# Show that exactly one x ∈ [0, ∞) exists with $x=\frac{1}4\cos^2(x)e^{-x}$

Tags: analysis

How can I show that exactly one $x ∈ [0, ∞)$ exists with $x=\frac{1}4\cos^2(x)e^{-x}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Presumably you mean. $$\frac{1}4\cos^2(x)e^{-x},$$ andd not some other grouping like $$\frac1{4\cos^2(x)}e^{-x}$$ or $$\frac{1}{4\cos^2(x)e^{-x}}.$$

Comment: Have you attempted to plot the functions defined by both sides and see in which approximate $x$ their graphical representation have a common point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that
$$f(x)=\frac14\cos^2(x)e^{-x}$$

You could show that $f(0)>0$ and $f(\pi/2)=0$, with $f'(x)<0$ on $(0,\pi/2)$. That means that there is only one value where $x=f(x)$ in this range (use the intermediate value theorem).

For $x>\pi/2$, you can show that $x>\frac14e^{-x}>f(x)$ so there is no other solution.